# Obj-C iPhone UISegmentedControl in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have 9 sections in my table (they get pulled from an array). In 4 sections, I'll have 1 row that pulls up a UIPickerView. In 5 of these sections, I'll need 5 different UISegmentedControls, with a varied number of selection options (2-5 options). Does anyone have any tips for me on implementing this?

Should I built separate xib files for every UISegmentedControl? I feel like there would/should be a better way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your table structure in a NSArray, so I would suggest you to create a NSDictionary for each row that should have a segmented control and add that to the table structure NSArray

You'll need three objects inside the dictionary. A title, a NSArray with the names of the segments, and you need a key you use to set and get the selected index.

I did something similar for the settings viewcontroller in some of my apps. This is how the NSDictionary looks like:

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  @"Value of Foo", kSettingsLabel,              // for the textLabel
  [UISegmentedControl class], kSettingsView,    // which UIControl
  @"foo", kSettingsKey,                         // the key for setValue:forKey: and valueForKey:
  [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Green", @"Round", @"Auto",nil], kSettingsValue,  // the titles of the segments
nil]
```

This is how I set up the UISegmentedControls in my tableview:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[self.dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// omitted: check in the dictionary which cell we need... (I wrote it that it can use almost all UIControls)
// omitted: dequeue a cell with a UISegmentedControl ... 
// configure cell:
NSArray *segmentTitles = [dictionary objectForKey:kSettingsValue];
UISegmentedControl *segment = (UISegmentedControl *)[cell viewWithTag:kTagSegment];
[segment removeAllSegments];
for (NSString *segmentName in segmentTitles) {
    // if index is higher than number of indexes title is inserted at last available index. 
    // so first object in array is placed at first position in segmentcontrol
    [segment insertSegmentWithTitle:segmentName atIndex:1000 animated:NO];
}
[segment setSelectedSegmentIndex:[[self valueForKey:[dictionary valueForKey:kSettingsKey]] intValue]];
//omitted: setup cell title ... and return cell
```

The UISegmentedControl is connected to a value changed action that looks like this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.settingsTable indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview]];
if (indexPath == nil)
    return;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[self.dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]) {
    [self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex] forKey:[dictionary valueForKey:kSettingsKey]];
}
```

and of course you need the setter and getter for the specified key too:

```
- (NSNumber *)foo {
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:someValue];
}

- (void)setFoo:(NSNumber *)n {
    someValue = [n intValue];
}
```

You could synthesize them but I wanted to have int value in my class instead of NSNumbers, so I wrote the setter and getter myself.

---

The big advantage of this is that it is completely dynamic. If you want to rearrange cells just shift them around in the array (I use a plist to make that even easier).

It's a little bit complicated when you use it for the first time, but it gets clear pretty fast. And you don't want five different .xibs and five different UISegmentedControls in your class interface.

Comment: So this way, I don't use any IB at all, right? This looks slightly more complex then what I'm looking for, as these rows will never need to be dynamic. I appreciate the effort of posting the code (this might actually get used in a different view in the app), but is there a different method you could recommend for a static table?

Comment: I used one .xib which has like 10 UITableViewCells for all the different cells I need. And to be honest with a static table I would do it almost the same way. Create a .xib with a cell layout and create the segment titles in code. When this is static there is no need for the dictionary or the key-value access. A `if (row == 1) /* setup cell */` with hardcoded values would be sufficient.

Comment: Great! In my case, I'd use 'if (section == 1) /* setup cell*/, but the idea remains the same. So then do something like [this blog post?](http://clingingtoideas.blogspot.com/2011/03/uitableview-how-to-part-4-xib-based.html) What's the advantage of setting up the segment titles in code instead of in IB? If I'm messing with IB anyway, wouldn't I save myself some coding by setting them in IB, or am I missing something here?

Comment: You can of course create each row in Interface Builder. There is no problem with that way. I usually don't do it because when I want to make the segment a little bit wider I had to do it on 5 cells. And I change the position of interface elements at least 10 times. And I ship all my apps in at least two languages, so the code way has another advantage. But there is nothing wrong with using interface builder. Do what works best for you. If you like doing it in IB, do it.

Answer (score 1):

In the `indexPath` object you have the ability to look at the `row` and the `section` of the tableview item. At that point you can then just decide what to display, your view, some text another view, whatever as the value of the `cell`. Remember that a cell is a UIView so you can add subviews and all of that. The Apple Documents for UITableView actually have a section on how to create static cells with controllers in them as well as how to override `cell` objects with other views.

Since everything is static, you can just check for the sections using a switch statement like this one in your regular `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"aCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) { 
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2
                                                  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease]; }
switch ([indexPath section]) {
    case 0:{
        cell.textLabel.text = @"The first section's cell";
        break;
    }
    case 1:{
        switch ([indexPath row]) {
            case 0:{
                //The first row of the second section
                break;
            }
            case 1:{
                //The second row of the second section
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                //The third row of the second section
                break;
        }


        }
        break;
    }   
    case 2:{
        //the third section
        break;
    }
    case 3:{
        //the fourth section
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Notes";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = currentClient.Notes;
        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
}

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this easily.

1. You can set the **tag** of the `UISegmentedControl` and access it like that.
2. You can programmatically create the control for each section. This would also require you to set the tag so you could access it in other methods.

These, in my opinion are the easiest ways to achieve what you are looking to do.

Both of these ways would require you to define the control in your header.

### .h

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    UISegmentedControl *myControl;
}
@property (nonatmoic, retain) UISegmentedControl *segment;
@end
```

### .m

```
#import "MyViewControler.h"
@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize myControl;
. . .
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on these methods please? I've already defined everything needed in my header, and synthesized them in my .m, but I can't figure out how to neatly decide which UISegmentedControl is going in which section.